# How can you edit/update part of state using BLoC pattern with StateNotifier?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am relatively new to Flutter and definitely new to state management with the BLoC pattern. I am working on a project of my own and doing state management using Provider + ChangeNotifier but I want to migrate to using the BLoC pattern with Riverpod + StateNotifier, as both new options seem superior. I was following ResoCoder's tutorial found here:
https://resocoder.com/2020/12/11/flutter-statenotifier-riverpod-tutorial-immutable-state-management/

He uses the example of a weather application that takes a user-specified City in a `TextField` and prints a fake Temperature for the given city. So basically there is a `Weather` model that has the properties `city` and `temperature`, and a `WeatherRepository` class that fetches and returns the Weather data for a given city.

Essentially, to handle the state, he first creates a set of classes of type `WeatherState` that model the different states in which the application can be in. These classes look like:

```
abstract class WeatherState {...} 
class WeatherInitial extends WeatherState {...}
class WeatherLoading extends WeatherState {...}
class WeatherLoaded extends WeatherState {
  //the below is an object that holds the "actual" application data to be passed to this WeatherState state in success/loaded situations.
  final Weather weatherObject;
  WeatherLoaded(this.weatherObject);
}
```

Afterwards, a StateNotifier is implemented by simply assigning different `WeatherState`s to the state depending on the logical state of the application, as such:

```
class WeatherNotifer extends StateNotifier<WeatherState>{
  // WeatherRepository holds the application logic for downloading weather data from the internet
    final WeatherRepository _weatherRepository;

  WeatherNotifier(this._weatherRepository) :       super(WeatherInitial());

  Future<void> getWeather(String cityName) async {
    try {
      state = WeatherLoading();
      final weather = await _weatherRepository.fetchWeather(cityName);
      state = WeatherLoaded(weather);
} on NetworkException {
      state = WeatherError("Couldn't fetch weather. Is the device online?");
    }
  }
}
```

The code above works perfectly for this application because the state of the application data is over-written with the results of `fetchWeather` each time and the entire cycle of states runs every time the a new city is submitted through the text-field.

However, how would I deal in scenarios where I want to edit PART of an already loaded state? I *know* that the state is immutable and I need to overwrite the state with a new state containing the changed value, but I am having trouble with the logic for accessing and editing this part of the state, because the "state" in the `StateNotifier` is of `WeatherState` type and not `Weather` type, so it is not holding the Weather object, which I wish to edit, directly. It is holding a WeatherState object, that ONLY holds a Weather object if the current WeatherState happens to be WeatherLoaded.

Eg: Let’s say we had an "Edit Weather" button that calls an `editWeather(double newTemperature)` method that after fetching the weather for a particular city, gives the user the option to edit the returned Temperature value and thus update the state. Where would the implementation of this method happen? How can you edit the Weather property of a state that is of type WeatherState, which may or may not have a Weather object depending on the current State?

I submitted this same question on the linked ResoCoder article, but I would appreciate any insight or help that anybody can offer praying

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes to the finished project:

### weather_notifier.dart

1. Add a new WeatherState `WeatherEdit`

```
class WeatherEdit extends WeatherState {
  final Weather weather;
  const WeatherEdit(this.weather);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object o) {
    if (identical(this, o)) return true;

    return o is WeatherEdit && o.weather == weather;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => weather.hashCode;
}
```

2. Add new methods `startWeatherEdit()` & `finishWeatherEdit()` to the `WeatherNotifier`

```
class WeatherNotifier extends StateNotifier<WeatherState> {
  ...

  Future<void> getWeather(String cityName) async {
    ...
  }

  void startWeatherEdit() {
    state = WeatherEdit((state as WeatherLoaded).weather);
  }

  void finishWeatherEdit(double newTemperature) {
    Weather newWeather = Weather(
        cityName: (state as WeatherEdit).weather.cityName,
        temperatureCelsius: newTemperature);

    state = WeatherLoaded(newWeather);
  }
}
```

### weather_search_page.dart

1. Update the Consumer

```
class _WeatherSearchPageState extends State<WeatherSearchPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     ...
          child: Consumer(
            builder: (context, watch, child) {
              final state = watch(weatherNotifierProvider.state);
              if (state is WeatherInitial) {
                return buildInitialInput();
              } else if (state is WeatherLoading) {
                return buildLoading();
              } else if (state is WeatherLoaded) {
                return buildColumnWithData(state.weather);
              } else if (state is WeatherEdit) {
                return buildWeatherEditUI(state.weather);
              } else {
                // (state is WeatherError)
                return buildInitialInput();
              }
            },
          ),
     ...
  }

  ...
}
```

2. Implement `buildWeatherEditUI()`

```
class _WeatherSearchPageState extends State<WeatherSearchPage> {
  ...

  Column buildWeatherEditUI(Weather weather) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          weather.cityName,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 40,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          // Display the temperature with 1 decimal place
          "${weather.temperatureCelsius.toStringAsFixed(1)} °C",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 80),
        ),
        WeatherEditField(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

// helper widget
class WeatherEditField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
      child: TextField(
        onSubmitted: (value) => submitWeatherEdit(context, value),
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Enter a new temperature",
          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
          suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.done),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void submitWeatherEdit(BuildContext context, String newTemperature) {
    context
        .read(weatherNotifierProvider)
        .finishWeatherEdit(double.parse(newTemperature));
  }
}
```

3. Finally, add the 'Edit Weather' button

```
class _WeatherSearchPageState extends State<WeatherSearchPage> {
  ...

  Column buildColumnWithData(Weather weather) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          ...
        ),
        Text(
          ...
        ),
        CityInputField(),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () =>
              context.read(weatherNotifierProvider).startWeatherEdit(),
          child: const Text('Edit Weather', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  ...
}
```